# Write the Python code that performs the following math calculation: (0.08√(x^2-8)+12)/(x+4)

Tags: python

This is from an assignment I got. I've been trying to find answers on google but nothing helps at all. So far I've done this. I'll appreciate any help!

```
x = int(input("Enter a value: "))

calculation = sqrt(0.08(x**2 - 8)) + 12 / x + 4
print (calculation)
```

Comment: `sqrt` is not a python function by default. You should import `math` library first by doing `import math` or `from math import sqrt`. And the square root is not placed correctly (look at your formula). Also you need the `*` symbol to multiply. Finally, you need parentheses for the denominator of that fraction.

Comment: What you want is some test cases that you know the answer for. Just write a function, then see if it gives the right answer for the known test cases. Also pay attention to where the parentheses are in the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are very close.  A couple of minor points - to multiply you always need the `*` operator - `0.08(...)` doesn't multiply the value in the brackets by 0.08.  Also, you forgot the brackets in a couple of places, e.g. around `x + 4`.

So this should work:

```py
from math import sqrt

x = int(input("Enter a value: "))

calculation = (sqrt(0.08*(x**2 - 8)) + 12) / (x + 4)
print (calculation)
```

Answer (score 0):

sqrt is from math library. Import it or you can use **0.5

**Method 1**

```py
calculation = ((0.08*(x**2 - 8))**0.5 + 12) / (x + 4)
```

**Method 2**

Importing math

```py
calculation = (math.sqrt(0.08*(x**2 - 8)) + 12) / (x + 4)
```